# Error Adding Multiple FK Relationship in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, relational-database

Consider we have two tables ProductType and ProductSizeGroup as below

**ProductType**

```
Id 
Name
MaleSizeGroupId
FemaleSizeGroupId
ChildSizeGroupId
```

**ProductSizeGroup**

```
Id
Name
```

Each of MaleSizeGroupId, FemaleSizeGroupId and ChildSizeGroupId fields should be FKs to ProductSizeGroup.Id.

I add one using the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductType]  
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT
    [FK_ProductType_ProductSizeGroup_Male] FOREIGN KEY([MaleGroupId]) 
    REFERENCES [dbo].[ProductSizeGroup] ([Id])
```

This works fine. I try to add the next using

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProductType]
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT
    [FK_ProductType_ProductSizeGroup_Female] FOREIGN KEY([FemaleGroupId]) 
    REFERENCES [dbo].[ProductSizeGroup] ([Id])
```

But I get the error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ProductType_ProductSizeGroup_Female". The conflict
>   occurred in database "dbname", table "dbo.ProductSizeGroup", column
>   'Id'.

So there is conflict.. but what conflict? What should I be looking for?

Comment: Is there existing data in the tables? Is there a value in `FemaleGroupId` that is not in `ProductSizeGroup.Id`?

Comment: Exactly the problem - didn't realise data was still in the tables (thought they had been cleaned down). Seems obvious now! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That just means: there are rows in your table `ProductType` that have values in the `FemaleGroupId` column which do **not exist** in the referenced table (`ProductSizeGroup`).

It's not a problem per se - you can totally have multiple columns going from one table to another.

The problem is with the existing data - you have data in there that doesn't live up to that FK constraint. Fix that data and you should be fine.

To find those offending rows, use a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[ProductType]
WHERE FemaleGroupId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM [dbo].[ProductSizeGroup])
```

That will list all offending rows - update their attribute and get going again!

Comment: As per my comment above - this was indeed the problem. I thought tables had been cleared of their data. Seems obvious, thanks for your help.